# Lightning Web Components Open Source with Lightning Design System (lwc with slds)

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am trying to local development with Lightning Web Component. The https://lwc.dev works good and I want to also add the Lightning Design System style but I am getting errors.

I have installed the style package `@salesforce-ux/design-system` and import it via:

```
async styleLoad() {
        await require('@salesforce-ux/design-system');
    }
```

But this does not work. The error message:

```
./src/modules/my/app/app.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@salesforce-ux/design-system' 
 in '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/CustomApp/src/modules/my/app'
```

Does someone any positive experience to import the lightning design system in a local lightning web component development.

PS: Everything works on Salesforce server or playground, my problem is: it does not work in local development environment (I am using `npm` as package manager).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't import the `@salesforce-ux/design-system` directly via require. If you look at the [`package.json`](https://github.com/salesforce-ux/design-system/blob/master/package.json), there is no `main` or `module` field designating the module entry point.

The current SLDS version is not compatible with the native shadow DOM (some selectors will attempt to style elements in different shadow trees). We are currently working on a new version of SLDS which better aligns with the shadow DOM restrictions. In the meantime, if you want to use SLDS + LWC standalone you will need to make sure the application runs with [`@lwc/synthetic-shadow`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lwc/synthetic-shadow).

---

The simplest way to add SLDS is to copy over the SLDS artifact to the `/dist` folder. Here is the commit containing the changes to enable SLDS in an lwc-create-app project: [commit](https://github.com/pmdartus/lwc-slds/commit/f5d96a261199c358bbada751e7bc5722b0562d82).

- install `@salesforce-ux/design-system` and `@lwc/synthetic-shadow` as an NPM dev dependency
- add the following line in the `resources` section `lwc-services.config.js` file to indicate that the SLDS artifacts should be copied over to the dist folder:

```js
{
    from: 'node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets',
    to: 'dist/resources/slds'
}
```

- import `@lwc/synthetic-shadow` before the `lwc` import in the `index.js` to force the framework to use the synthetic shadow DOM instead of the native one provided by the browser.

```js
import '@lwc/synthetic-shadow';
```

Comment: Thank you @pmdartus, this is really helpful. I am looking for the new version of SLDS.

Comment: @pmdartus - while i have some experience in developing lwc's within a scratch org.. I am new to the open source version at lwc.dev. I followed the advice you gave (and referenced your commit) to upgrade my project to have the SLDS assets. Should this have given me the ability to use `ShowToastEvent`?

I got an error - `Cannot find module 'lightning/platofrmShowToastEvent'`

Comment: One thing I wanted to point out --  the synthetic-shadow allows you to import any CSS framework and have it propagate down to be available to all LWC components in the solution.   I am currently using it with Tailwind.  You just need to reference the stylesheet in your root index.html.

Comment: Does anybody knows if we have any update regarding this? Is it SLDS already available lwc applications?

Comment: @pmdartus Was that both dependencies as `--save-dev` or just one of them?